# POSTGRESQL question: How to store and use a calculated field based on different status of a column?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named transactions where  it has a column named `type`, and a column named `orderID`, and a column named `status`

```
type | orderID | status | dollar_amount
__________________________________________
sale  | 123   | approved | 3.23
tax   | 123   | approved | 0.74
refund| 123   | approved | 3.21
sale  | 456   | rejected | 2.98
```

`type` could be `'sale'`, `'tax'`, and `'refund'`, `status` could be 'rejected' or 'approved'

I want to calculate a field where I can calculate sums of all 'sale' and 'tax' transactions, minus sum of all 'refund' on the `status` of `'approved'`, all grouped by `orderID`

I am stuck on getting the status of my transactions and calculating them in one setting...
any pointers appreciated

what I have right now

```
select sum(dollar_amount) as grosssale 
from transactions l 
where l.status = 'approved'
and (type = 'sale' or type = 'tax'))
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: edited @stickybit

Answer (score 0):

I recommend defining a view on the table and add a column that is calculated using a window function:

```
CREATE VIEW transaction_plus AS
SELECT orderid, dollar_amount, type, status,
       sum(dollar_amount) FILTER (WHERE type IN ('sale', 'tax') OVER w -
       sum(dollar_amount) FILTER (WHERE type = 'refund' AND status = 'apploved') OVER w
FROM transactions
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY orderid);
```

I hope I have understood your formula right; if not, adjust the query to your needs.